# IntelliJ build jar, view command used

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I have setup intellij to build a working jar file for the project.  However, I need to be able to see what command is being used to generate this, so I can build it directly from the command line.

Any ideas?

Many thanks,

Sam

Comment: What project type are you using? Ant, Gradle or Maven?

Comment: Couldn't you see it in the event log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to use Build -> Generate Ant Build from menu. It will create an ant file that will build the project.